# Django creating file - [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, django, file, pdf

I'm trying to create a huge PDF file (arround 300MB) and I'm getting this error:

```
error at /generar-pdf/7/AoyZ1431Az
[Errno 111] Connection refused
```

This is the full error
[image]

And this is the view that generates de PDF:

```
def generar_libro(request, book, order):
    try:
        book = Book.objects.get(pk=int(book))
        order = Order.objects.get(identificador=pedido, cuento=book)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    file_name = randstring(25)

    data = {}
    data = ast.literal_eval(order.data)
    data['order'] = order

    # Render html content through html template with context
    template = get_template(order.book.template_html)
    html  = template.render(Context(data))

    # Write PDF to file
    fullfilename = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + "/pdfs/", file_name + ".pdf")
    fichero = open(fullfilename, "w+b")
    pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode('utf-8'), dest=fichero,
            encoding='utf-8')

    # Return PDF document through a Django HTTP response
    fichero.seek(0)
    pdf = fichero.read()
    fichero.close()            # Don't forget to close the file handle

    order.url_pdf = '%s.pdf' % file_name
    order.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('single', kwargs={'order': order.pk}))
```

I'm trying with another PDF that only weight 25MB and it's working. So I think it might be the weight, anyone knows a posible solution?

EDIT: I'm using Apache

Thanks

Comment: are you using nginx or is this problem occurring at development itself without nginx or apache. Also try logging time and post the complete error log.

Comment: check what is the file size limitation in apache's config file. Mean while also check if the problem occurs if you try to create PDF without connecting through Apache.

Comment: @Sar009 I tried without Apache and I have the same problem :S
But not in my local computer

Comment: ok i suppose there is some kind of timeout or may be out of memory error(more possible) happening. Because anyway you are not returning the pdf object you created and it is in the memory just comment `pdf = fichero.read()` and try. also please post the complete error log.

Comment: Still with the same error. Maybe is the memory but it's weird because it crashes instantly.. Here is the traceback report: http://dpaste.com/19TAY7E

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58247/discussion-between-sar009-and-marcos-aguayo).

Comment: @MarcosAguayo could you please post root cause or answer?